# Angular: loading external javascript in Html page

Tags: javascript, angular, aspnetboilerplate

I have an Angular 6 project (used AspNetBoilerplate) and trying to integrate it with a credit card payment gateway. Below is the html snippet that I am supposed to use to load up their iFrame in my solution:

```
<script src="https://secure.ewaypayments.com/scripts/eCrypt.js"
   class="eway-paynow-button"
   data-publicapikey="epk-VSGG8494-DAE1-4568-3465-50XXDDT450F"
   data-amount="1000"
   data-currency="AUD" >
</script>
```

For some reason it does not load up the iFrame when I have it in my angular pages. It works fine when I have it in one of my html pages outside of the angular module. In the browser debugger it does not seem loading the javascript file.

Answer (score 0):

Since angular5 or 6 you can't add anymore scripts tag inside of your components templates. you have to use the script tag in the index.html or import the script into your angular.json conf file and then bind it into a var in your component to use his functions.

maybe watch out this [link](https://medium.com/@balramchavan/integrating-google-maps-in-angular-5-ca5f68009f29) who integrate google map in an angular app. The principle is about the same.

Hope this help.